# Pointer arithmetic in array of strings

Tags: c

I am reading a linux programming with c language book and it has the following code.

```
        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int opt;
        while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "iv")) != -1) {
            switch (opt) {
            case 'i':
                opt_ignorecase = 1;
                break;
            case 'v':
                opt_invert = 1;
                break;
            case '?':
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-iv] [<file>...]\n", argv[0]);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;
}
```

I don't understand that why argv += optind works.
When i tried at another program, which is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    
    char* test[] = {"Hello", "World", "I"};
    argv += 1;
    test += 1;
    printf("%s", test[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

the gcc compiler shows error

```
a.c:8:9: error: assignment to expression with array type
8 |    test += 1;
```

the += on argv works but doesn't work with test.
I don't understand which part I did wrong..

Comment: `char* argv[]` as a function parameter is a different way to write `char** argv`. So, it is a pointer to a pointer, `test` is an array of pointer

Answer (score 3):

When an array declaration appears in a function parameter list, it is automatically adjusted to declare a pointer. So `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` actually declares `argv` to have type `char **`.

Since `argv` is a pointer, we can increment it with `argv += optind;`. `argv` initially points to the first of several `char *`, and `argv += optind;` changes which of those `char *` it points to.

In contrast, the declaration `char* test[] = {"Hello", "World", "I"};` defines `test` to be an array of `char *`. Since it is an array, it cannot be moved; `test += 1` attempts to change where the array is, and that is not allowed.

After defining `test`, you could define a new pointer, `char **p = test;`, and then you could adjust `p` with `p += 1;`. (Note that in `char **p = test;`, `test` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so this is equivalent to `char **p = &test[0];`.)

(Note: Grammatically, the `*` in `char * test []` binds with `test []`, not `char`, so `char* test[]` is misleading. A declaration such as `char* a, b;` would not declare both `a` and `b` to be `char*`. It declares `a` to be `char *` and `b` to be `char`, so `char *a, b;` is a better picture of the meaning.)

Comment: Hi eric, thank you for your explanation. After trying to do something like 
char *hello[] = {"Hello", "I", "am", "Low"};
    char ** test = hello;
it works. 
By the way, a little out of topic, whats the downside if i do something like above?

Comment: @nicklowkc: There is not much downside by itself, and I would not worry about it until you are further along in learning C and programming. One downside is that form requires two identifiers, `hello` and `test`, whereas it can be done with one, `char **test = (char *[]) {"Hello", "I", "am", "Low"};`. But there are other considerations in the context of a program, such as whether the array should be static or automatic, whether you need to reset to the beginning, whether the same strings are used elsewhere, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`argv` doesn't have array type, despite how the declaration is written; its actual type is `char **`.

In a function parameter list, any declaration of the form `T a[N]` or `T a[]` is *adjusted* to `T *a` - all three declare `a` as a pointer, not an array.  This is *only* true for function parameter declarations, not regular declarations.